# Solr fields types

Tags: java, solr

I have a class like this

public class Item implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * Serialization id for item.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Unique identifier for the item which contains documentId prefixed with organization short name Example: walmart!some-item-id .
 */
@Id
@Field
@NotNull
@Getter @Setter private String itemId;

/**
 * Stores multiple long description for an item.
 */
@Field
@Getter @Setter private Set<ItemLongDescription> itemLongDescriptions;

/**
 * Stores multiple short description for an item.
 */
@Field
@Getter @Setter private Set<ItemShortDescription> itemShortDescriptions;
```

}

i want to store this class in solr. Can anyone suggest me what are the fields or fieldtypes i need to configure in Schema.xml.

Right now for itemLongDescriptions and itemShortDescriptions i create fields as strings. So they are storing in solr as

{

```
    "itemId":"Walma!null",

    "itemLongDescriptions":["com.sample.s.new.item.ItemLongDescription:en-US"],
    "itemShortDescriptions":["com.sample.s.new.item.ItemShortDescription:en-US"],
    "_version_":1538407665183490048}]
```

}

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do with the data. If you just want to keep it available or match it exactly, string is fine. If you want to tokenized it (split it into separate tokens) to search for single words, or process it some other way, you'll have to define a field that matches how you want that done.

Comment: My question can be filter as, can we store  set<POJO> in solr where POJO is custom objects rather solr fields(like string, integer) etc?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you're doing now?

Comment: Yeah but the field is String rather than my custom POJO object ItemLongDescription

Comment: No, the your library would have to handle serializing/deserializing POJOs in that case. There is no object / pojo datatype in Solr as far as I know.

Comment: I kept a toString in ItemLongDescription and changed Set<ItemLongDescription> to Set<String> and save that in solr as array of strings.and  It worked  ------------------------------                                                                                        {
        "itemId":"itemId61",
        "itemLongDescriptions":["description : Frozen foods, locale : en-   US", "description : Frozoan foods, locale : fr-FR"],
        "itemShortDescriptions":["description : Frozen, locale : en-US",
          "description : Frozan, locale : fr-FR"],
        "_version_":1538478755557670912}